# How to draw a hyperplane using the weights calculated

Tags: neural-network

In the simple example where I have **n** input neurons, I can consider this to be a point in a n-dimensional space.

If the output layer is just one neuron with value **0** or **1**, if I get convergence, the neural net should define a hyperplane dividing the two classes of points - those mapped to **0** and those mapped to **1**. How do I calculate this hyperplane using the **(n,1)** matrix of weights I calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only an input layer, one set of weights, and an output layer, you can solve this directly with $$ X \cdot w = threshold $$

However if you add in hidden layers, you no longer necessarily have a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane), as in order to be a hyperplane it must be able to be expressed as the "solution of a single algebraic equation of degree 1."

Even if you can't solve directly, you can still get a sense for the response surface by evaluating your network's output over a wide range of inputs.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better to way to think about a neural net as you have it written is that it is a function.

$$f_{nn} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$$

which is generally a non-linear decision boundary. You did not indicate your network structure and activation function. If your data is linearly separable then a single layer perceptron will define weights for you in the input layer, plus a bias input node for the intercept.

If you specifically want a separating hyperplane you could consider support vector machines. See here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8021219/431895